# Pandas groupby apply list - Ensure it preserves order

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm kinda new to pandas and ran into the following line of code

```
df.groupby(by=['id']).agg(lambda x: list(x))
```

here `df` is

```
   id var_x var_y
0   1   xe  ye
1   1   xb  yb
2   1   xc  yc
3   2   xd  yd
4   3   xe  ye
5   1   xa  ya
6   2   xf  yf
```

It gives the (expected) result

```
       var_x                 var_y
id      
1   [xe, xb, xc, xa]    [ye, yb, yc, ya]
2           [xd, xf]            [yd, yf]
3               [xe]                [ye]
```

The question is can we ensure that the agregates for each variable share the same order?
E.g. with `id=1`, is there any way to explain that we won't have `[xe, xb, xc, xa]` and `[ya, ye, yc, yb]` instead of `[xe, xb, xc, xa]` and `[ye, yb, yc, ya]`?

Comment: Additional information from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), if it matters: _"Groupby preserves the order of rows within each group"_

Comment: @Timus do you mind if I add this ref to my answer?

Comment: @mozway Not at all, pease do if it seems useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### short answer

Yes, the order is ensured.

###### documentation

The documentation of [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) indicates that you can sort the **groups**, but that in any case **the order of the rows is preserved**.

> sortbool, default True
>
> Sort group keys. Get better performance by turning this off. Note this does not influence the order of observations within each group.
> **Groupby preserves the order of rows within each group.**

###### details

`groupby.agg` passes entire Series to the aggregation function, group by group, then the same for the next columns.

You can check this by running `print`:

```
df.groupby(by=['id']).agg(print)

0    xe
1    xb
2    xc
5    xa
Name: var_x, dtype: object
3    xd
6    xf
Name: var_x, dtype: object
4    xe
Name: var_x, dtype: object
0    ye
1    yb
2    yc
5    ya
Name: var_y, dtype: object
3    yd
6    yf
Name: var_y, dtype: object
4    ye
Name: var_y, dtype: object
```

###### order within the lists

This is equivalent to running `list(Series)` for each processed Series. `list` does not modify the order of the passed iterable, so the order is preserved.